# Late-2011 MacBook Pro’s and Snow Leopard

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

Has any member here performed a software downgrade from the pre-installed Lion 10.7.2 to Snow leopard 10.6.8 on any late-2011 MacBook Pro (any size) and if it was successful or failed and what you found? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven’t done this but from research it is possible:

[This article helped](https://gigaom.com/2011/07/26/how-to-downgrade-from-lion-to-snow-leopard/)

> **Method 1: If you have no cooked backup of your drive**
>
> This method will wipe your Mac but you can do a backup:
>
> 1. You should backup the locations where your documents, music e.t.c are stored to an external drive
> 2. Next insert the snow Leopard disk, restart your Mac and hold down c too boot to your dvd drive
> 3. Once the installer appears, go to utilities in the menu bar and click disk Utility
> 4. Find the drive in the sidebar where Lion is installed, select it and navigate to the Partition tab.
> 5. Click on the drop down menu under Partition Layout and select “1 Partition.” Hit Apply.
> 6. Now navigate to the Erase tab and make sure “Mac OS Extended (Journaled)” is selected, then hit Erase to delete all data on the
>    drive.
> 7. Quit Disk Utility to get back to the Snow Leopard installer and proceed with the install.
> 8. Restore your User folder and documents from your backup.
> 9. Run Software Update to get  everything current, install your apps  from your original install media and  update those as well.
>
> **Method 2: If you managed to clone  your drive**
>
> A popular option for cloning your drive is Carbon Copy Cloner, which
> is a handy utility to have for any Mac owner. Assuming you’ve done
> that, follow the directions above to get your drive primed and ready,
> but stop at step 6 and follow these instructions instead.
>
> 1. Attach the drive containing your  CCC clone to your Mac.
> 2. Open System Preferences, then  go to the Startup Disk preference  pane.
> 3. Chose your CCC external drive  as the startup disk.
> 4. Restart and launch CCC, then  choose your backup from the  “source” menu.
> 5. Select your Mac’s internal drive  as the destination.
> 6. Chose “Restore items from a  backup” from the settings pop-up  menu and hit the “Clone” button.